# Compiling SASS on El Capitan: map for 'map-has-key' error

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

When trying to compile an SCSS file, it is throwing an error of:

$map: 20px is not a map for 'map-has-key'

It refuses to compile and results in no styling on the site.

I'm using 'Foundation Sites' as the framework.

OS: OS X El Capitan
Compass, SASS, Grunt, XCode and Ruby.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I've tried updating all of the above applications, reinstalling, etc, to no avail.

Comment: Where is the code that reproduces the error?  What part of `$map: 20px is not a map for 'map-has-key'` don't you understand?  The error sounds pretty darn clear to me.  Also, do not use tags unless they are directly related to the problem (ie. a Grunt expert is probably not going to be able to help you with a problem like this).

Comment: The code is in Foundation itself, nothing I've written. Line 215 breakpoint.scss: @else if map-has-key($map, $value) { - the problem is not the code I believe; it works on other machines running anything other than El Capitan.

Comment: Did you overwrite any variables at all?  What version of Sass are you using (and Compass, if you're using that)?

Comment: Compass v1.0.3, Sass v3.4.22 - no variables have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting foundation-sites version to 6.1.0 fixed this issue. It seems Foundation has a bug when being compiled on the latest Sass and on El Capitan.